# change Microsoft exchange calender from ASP.net page

Tags: asp.net, calendar, outlook, exchange-server, outlook-addin

I have a meeting schedule system that schedules meeting time. 
I would like to make an ASP.net /C# application that can edit the Microsoft Exchange calender of my organization from the ASP.net page. The exchange calender is present in Microsoft Outlook.

For retrieving calender information by importing the calender in .ics format. the following might be useful (Although I did not try) 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17980/Adding-iCalendar-Support-to-Your-Program-Part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is for Office 365 customers, you can use [our .NET library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/adding-service-to-your-Visual-Studio-project) that uses [Office 365 REST APIs for calendar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations). If you are targeting an on-premises Exchange server, then you can use [EWS Managed API](https://github.com/officedev/ews-managed-api) and use "Exchange 2013 Create meetings programmatically" code sample from [Exchange 2013 101 Code Samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/exchange/Exchange-2013-101-Code-3c38582c).  Hope this helps ...

Thanks,

Venkat

Comment: Specifically the folloing two links solves the problem https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/exchange/Exchange-2013-Create-79148637#content   https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/exchange/Exchange-2013-Retrieve-a-ab4a677a#content

Answer (score 1):

one can edit the exchange calender by sending an appointment email to the client. this seems to be the most proper way to change one Exchange calender 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24817/Send-appointment-through-email-in-ASP-NET?fid=1164404&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&prof=False&sort=Position&view=Normal&spc=Relaxed